# recap for me datagrid sorting and view state please

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

how does it work when i have a data grid that i want page able and sortable, do i use view state? does the data get pulled once and then the view state keeps all the data and grid working, sortable, page able?

or do i need to go to the db server each time i page and sort?

help clarify this point for me please.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the built in paging without a SqlDataSource object, your data will be paged in memory, which can be a massive overhead.

ViewState will by default retain the information in the grid, however the data item for each row won't be available after a postback.

If you are dealing with large volumes of data, then paging and sorting should be done on the database so as littel data as possible is transferred to the web app.